# skip first element using .append()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to skip the first I'm loading up with .append() I'm not sure  how to do it.

here is the code I'm using.

```
 $.each(get_images, function(i,img){
  $('#container ul').append('<li><img src="'+img+'"/></li>'); 
});
```

Comment: I don't see the answer being very efficient unless you give us your `html`.

Comment: I'm confused. You want to skip the first iteration of the loop, or you want to not append to the first element returned by `$('#container ul')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice` method to skip `1` element, for sample:

```
$(get_images).slice(1).each(function(i, img) {
   $('#container ul').append('<li><img src="'+img+'"/></li>'); 
});
```

Or also, you can check the index:

```
$.each(get_images, function(i, img) {
  if (i > 0) {
     $('#container ul').append('<li><img src="'+img+'"/></li>'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: *"An integer indicating the 0-based position at which the elements begin to be selected. If negative, it indicates an offset from the end of the set."* - Shouldn't it be `slice(0)`? (honest question, didnt know about slice method).

Comment: `0-based` means the first element is `0` and the `start` parameter indicates the amount of elements the method will skip, so, 1 will skip the first element :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code its an example:

```
not(':first-child')
```

like

```
$('ul li').not(':first-child').each(function ()
    {
       /// your code

    });
```

Comment: if this solved your question please mark it as correct thanx..:)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you are trying to skip the first element in the `$.each`, I would do something like:

```
$.each( get_images, function( index, img ) {
    if( index > 0 ) {
        // this skips the first index of the $.each loop
    }
}
```

Some of the comments suggest that you wanted to append it after the first `li` tag, if that is the case, try what @Tushar suggested.

Comment: would be `>0` since it's a 0 based index or `>=1`.